# .htaccess slicing first two characters from GET for forwarding path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hey guys I got a tricky one here, but I believe it will allow me to bypass the need for a PHP controller file for forwarding. I have a url that I hit `example.com/` if it has no following sequence, it will route like this

```
#example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www\.example2\.com/?CampID=dm/DMdefault [R=301,L]
```

The question is the second redirect. If I want to slice the first two (alphanum) as one part of the forwarding url, and the next five as the second part, would this work?

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})(\w{5})$ http://www\.example2\.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/${lc:$1}?CampId=${lc:$1$2} [R=301,L]
```

This *should normalize case, and forward `http://example.com/BA025JD` to 
`http://www.example2.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/ba?CampId=ba025jd` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `RewriteMap` directive inside an htaccess file, you need to define maps in server or vhost config. Unfortunately, apache chooses not to bring that to your attention. If you use a map that hasn't been defined, it just silently does nothing.

However, once that map has been defined, your rules work for me:

**my request**

```
GET /A1b2C3d HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

**apache's response, with the *lc* map defined**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 15 Oct 2012 18:44:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.example2.com/landing/external-marketing/direct-mail/a1?CampId=a1b2c3d
Content-Length: 349
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Awesome, actually its in my httpd.conf but I threw it in there so everyone knew what lc was an alias for ;) thanks Jon, much obliged for confirming for me